# Catching 403 from $.ajax promise in jQuery v1.x

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest, jquery-deferred

I'm having problems with catching 403 from `$.ajax` promise in jQuery v1.x.

The same code

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: 'http://www.checkupdown.com/accounts/grpb/B1394343/',
    type: 'GET'
}).then(function () {
    console.log('success', arguments)
}, function () {
    console.log('error', arguments)
});
```

rejects the promise as expected [in jQuery v2.x](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdzZwW?editors=001) but logs nothing [in jQuery v1.x](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojxoQP?editors=001) (the promise has `readyState == 1`).

The examples use 2.1.3 and 1.11.3 jQuery versions respectively.

Why exactly does this happen? Is it solvable for jQuery v1?

Comment: 1.x being, 1.11.x? or 1.7, 1.4, what? 1.x is a pretty broad range covering roughly 7, maybe 8 years worth of versions.

Comment: @KevinB Legitimate question, I've recently had problems with old jQuery. No, it is 1.11.3, which should reflect 2.1.4 closely, in theory.

Comment: I'm more surprised that you're able to get an error message in 2.x, rather than that you're not getting one in 1.x. Adding a timeout might be an acceptable workaround.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks, I already did it as a quick fix, but rejection on timeout isn't the same as getting 403 immediately. Though it is better than stalled promise, you can post it as an answer if you wish.

Comment: Right, but you're dealing with JSONP, which isn't an XHR request, and therefore has very poor error handling options. Having a timeout error on a failed ajax request is far better than having no error callback on a failed ajax request.

Comment: Like i said, i'd be more curious about how 2.x is handling it, If it's reproducible you could use the same technique with 1.11.x. Only way to find out would be to go to the source, or open a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They perform differently because in 1.11.x, an error event handler is not attached to the script tag, instead all you have is an onload or onreadystatechange handler.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.11.3/src/ajax/script.js#L57

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.1.3/src/ajax/script.js#L44

There is no workaround other than using a timeout or performing the jsonp request yourself.

Comment: Thank you for this investigation, this makes sense now, that's the kind of the answer I wanted to get.

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky because you're not making a real AJAX request.  JSON-P is a hack, and will cause all sorts of problems for you.

If you really want to detect errors reliably, you need to use a real AJAX request.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm limited to JSONP for API I'm using because of CORS.

Comment: @estus Then you aren't going to be able to reliably detect errors.  Use a server-side proxy.

Comment: What I'm curious about is why v1 behaves in such manner. Is that a bug or desired behaviour for the sake of browser compatibility?

Comment: @estus I'm not sure... it could go either way.  You might consider posting a bug report.